# I am trying to retrieve a webpage html with webclient and display it with webbrowser in C#

Tags: browser, webclient

I have the following code snippet:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String htmlCode = client.DownloadString(newurl);
webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmlCode;
```

BTW, webBrowser1 is defined globally elsewhere in the program. Likewise, "newurl" is a valid url also defined globally elsewhere.

WebClient gets the complete html which I pass to webbrowser1 using DocumentText.

This result is all kinds of link, syntax, remote javascript, and other errors as though the html is corrupted. However, if I use

```
webbrowser1.Navigate(newurl);
```

the target page displays just fine.

I am getting the source html so I can make changes before I display it.

Clearly I am missing something.

Any thoughts?

Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

`webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmlCode;` will set the HTML only, but will not load any linked-in resources, such as JS, images, CSS, ... .

If you want to do, what you seem to want to do, you can e.g. load the HTML via a `WebClient`, rewrite it (this includes changing relative paths to absolute ones or setting a base url), write it to a file, then `webbrowser1.Navigate("file://path/to/file");`

Comment: Thanks you, but I need a little help.  I understand making relative paths absolute, but what is and how does one set a "base url" given I have a file with the html in it and will use webbrowser1.Navigate(<myfile>);

Comment: **Instead of** making the paths absolute, you can **alternativly** set a base uri. Assuming your original URL is `http://domain.tld/something.html`, you can leave alone the paths in the HTML by adding `<base href="http://domain.tld">` in the `head` element.

Comment: Thank you again.  I editied the html I retrieved and changed all relative urls to absolute and referenced the file in IE and it worked like a charm.  Again my thinks.  Jim